# Multiple forms in one view Laravel 5.1

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, laravel-routing

I have a problem. Someone could tell me can i use couple forms in one vie on one route? I mean i have three forms with post method in show.blade.php in show function in ProfileController which showing users profiles. I posting 3 forms in this view,and in route i have something like this:

```
Route::post('profile/{id}', MessageController@store');// this is private message to other user

Route::post('profile/{id}', CommentController@store'); //this is comment to profile

Route::post('profile/{id}', CommentController@storeCommit'); // this is answer to comment profile
```

I dont know what i doing wrog,but this isdont work,i mean if i delete CommitStore route i can send message and add comment,but if i add this storeCommit i cant add comment,because i getting error, field from storeCommit cannot be null. Tomorrow i add code from controllers and view. Someone have any idea, please, help me, thanks.

This is View which has three forms, Sending Messages, Adding Comment to Profile and Adding Answer to Comment in profile:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')


<div>

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#info" aria-controls="info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Informacje</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#postacie" aria-controls="postacie" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Postacie</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#posty" aria-controls="posty" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Posty</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#komentarze" aria-controls="komentarze" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Komentarze</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="info">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr class="active">
                    <td> Avatar </td>
                    <td> Informacje </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="info">
                    <td>

                        <img src="{{$user->avatar}}" width="150px" height="150px" alt="Avatar" class="img-circle"> <BR /><BR />
                        @if(!\Auth::guest() && $user->id == \Auth::user()->id)
                        <a style="text-align:right" href="/profile/{{$user->id}}/edit"<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edytuj profil</button></a>   
                        @endif  

                        @if(!\Auth::guest() && \Auth::id() != $user->id)
                        <button style="float:right" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                        @endif

                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Wyślij wiadomość do {{$user->name}}</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        {!! Form::model(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['MessageController@store', $user->id]]) !!}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Wprowadź tytuł wiadomości' ]) !!}
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Wprowadź wiadomość' ]) !!}
                                        </div>

                                        {!! Form::hidden('mess_to_user', $user->id) !!}
                                        {!! Form::hidden('from_user_name', $user->name) !!}

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        {!! Form::submit('Wyślij wiadomość', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

                                    </div>
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    @include('errors.list')
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </td>

                    <td width="960">
                        {!!$user->showName($user->name)!!}

                        @if($user->is_online == 1)
                        <span class="label label-success">Online</span>
                        @else
                        <span class="label label-danger">Offline</span>     
                        @endif  

                        <BR />

                        @foreach($user->group as $group)
                        <strong>Grupa użytkownika:</strong> {{$group->name}}
                        @endforeach

                        <BR />
                        <strong>Dołączył dnia:</strong> {{$user->created_at->diffForHumans()}} <BR />
                        <strong>Wiek: </strong>{{$user->age}}
                        <strong>Płeć: </strong>{{$user->formatSex($user->sex)}} <BR />


                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                        Sygnatura użytkownika {{$user->name}}
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    @if(empty($user->signature))
                                    Brak sygnatury
                                    @else
                                    {!! $user->signature !!}
                                    @endif  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table class="table table-condensed">

                <!-- Tabela na KONTAKTY-->
                <tr>

                    <!--SOCIAL-->
                    <td>
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="active">
                                    @if(empty($user->skype))
                                    <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple6/v4/1e/0c/96/1e0c9683-1019-f450-f07e-017b6f0012c6/icon175x175.png" width="16" height="16" /> <span class="label label-warning">Niezdefiniowano</span>
                                    @else
                                    <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple6/v4/1e/0c/96/1e0c9683-1019-f450-f07e-017b6f0012c6/icon175x175.png" width="16" height="16" /> {{$user->skype}}
                                    @endif  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="active">
                                    @if(empty($user->facebook))
                                    <img src="http://blogs-images.forbes.com/peterhimler/files/2014/02/high-res-logo_facebook1.png" width="16" height="16" /> <span class="label label-warning">Niezdefiniowano</span>
                                    @else
                                    <img src="http://blogs-images.forbes.com/peterhimler/files/2014/02/high-res-logo_facebook1.png" width="16" height="16" /> <a href="{{$user->facebook}}">{{$user->facebook}}</a>
                                    @endif  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="active">
                                    @if(empty($user->twitter))
                                    <img src="http://health.uri.edu/files/twitter.png" height="16" width="16" /> <span class="label label-warning">Niezdefiniowano</span>
                                    @else
                                    <img src="http://health.uri.edu/files/twitter.png" height="16" width="16" /> <a href="{{$user->twitter}}">{{$user->twitter}}</a>
                                    @endif  
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>

                    <!--GAME-->
                    <td width="50%">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="active">
                                    @if(empty($user->xfire))
                                    <img src="http://img06.deviantart.net/ebd6/i/2008/045/6/3/xfire_enhanced_icon_by_sparticusx.jpg" height="16" width="16" /> <span class="label label-warning">Niezdefiniowano</span>
                                    @else
                                    <img src="http://img06.deviantart.net/ebd6/i/2008/045/6/3/xfire_enhanced_icon_by_sparticusx.jpg" height="16" width="16" /> {{$user->xfire}}
                                    @endif  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="active">
                                    @if(empty($user->steam))
                                    <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/clickerheroes/images/5/54/Logo-Steam.png/revision/latest?cb=20150529052012" height="16" width="16" /> <span class="label label-warning">Niezdefiniowano</span>
                                    @else
                                    <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/clickerheroes/images/5/54/Logo-Steam.png/revision/latest?cb=20150529052012" height="16" width="16" /> <a href="{{$user->steam}}">{{$user->steam}}</a> 
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="active">
                                    @if(empty($user->origin))
                                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/525760420192083969/Tv_fRfVF_400x400.png" height="16" width="16" /> <span class="label label-warning">Niezdefiniowano</span>
                                    @else
                                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/525760420192083969/Tv_fRfVF_400x400.png" height="16" width="16" /> {{$user->origin}}
                                    @endif  
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="postacie">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr class="active">
                    <td>
                        @forelse($user->player as $player)


                        <button type="button" style="width:200px; height:200px" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$player->id}}">{!!$player->checkActive($player->active)!!}<BR />{!! Html::image('skin/Skin_'.$player->skin.'.png') !!}<BR/>
                            {{$player->formatName($player->name)}}  </button>

                            @empty
                            @if(!\Auth::guest() && $user->id == \Auth::user()->id)
                            <center><p><a href="/character/create"><h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></h1></a></p></center>
                            @else
                            <center><h1><span class="label label-default">Brak postaci!</span></h1></center>    
                            @endif

                            @endforelse
                        </td>   
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="posty">...</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="komentarze">
                <BR />
                @if(!\Auth::guest())
                <div class="panel panel-warning">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Dodaj komentarz do profilu użytkownika {!!$user->showName($user->name)!!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {!! Form::model(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['CommentController@store', $user->id]]) !!}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::text('comment', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Wprowadź komentarz do tego profilu ' ]) !!}
                        </div>

                        {!! Form::hidden('to_user', $user->id) !!}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::submit('Dodaj komentarz', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                        </div>

                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        @include('errors.list')
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endif

                @forelse($user->queryComment($comments, $user->id) as $com)
                <div class="panel panel-primary">

                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Komentarz od <a style="color:white" href="/profile/{{$com->user_id}}">{{$com->name}}</a> <span class="label label-warning">{{$com->created_at}}</span>
                        @if(!\Auth::guest())
                        <button style="float:right" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$com->id}}">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                        </button>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{$com->comment}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{$com->id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    Pokaż wszystkie komentarze
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapse{{$com->id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                            @forelse($user->queryCommit($commits, $com->id) as $commit)
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="panel panel-success">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title">Podkomentarz od <a href="/profile/{{$commit->user_id}}">{{$commit->user_name}}</a> <span class="label label-warning">{{$commit->created_at}}</span> </h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        {{$commit->body}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @empty
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                Brak podkomentarzy!
                            </div>  
                            @endforelse
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$com->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Dodaj komentarz</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    {!! Form::model(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['CommentController@storeCommit', $user->id]]) !!}

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {!! Form::text('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Wprowadź adnotację do wybranego komentarza ' ]) !!}
                                    </div>
                                    {!! Form::hidden('to_comment', $com->id) !!}
                                    {!! Form::hidden('to_user_com_id', $user->id) !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    {!! Form::submit('Dodaj komentarz', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                                </div>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                                @include('errors.list')
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                @empty
                <p>Brak komentarzy w profilu</p>

                @endforelse
                {!!$comments->render()!!}
            </div>
            @include('errors.list')

            @foreach($user->player as $p)
            @include('character.show')
            @endforeach


        </div>


        @stop
```

This is MessageController and CommentController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\CommentRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\CommitRequest;
use App\Comment;
use App\Commit;


class CommentController extends Controller
{

    public function store(CommentRequest $request) 
    { 
        \Auth::user()->comment()->create([
            'comment' => $request->input('comment'),
            'to_user' => $request->input('to_user'),
            'from_name' => \Auth::user()->name
            ]);

        flash()->success('Komentarz został dodany!');
        return redirect('/profile/'.$request->input('to_user').'');
    } 

    public function storeCommit(CommitRequest $request)
    {
            Commit::create(
                [
                    'body' => $request->input('body'),
                    'to_comment' => $request->input('to_comment'),
                    'user_name' => \Auth::user()->name,
                    'from_user_id' => \Auth::id(),
                    'to_user_com_id' => $request->input('to_user_com_id')
                ]);

            flash()->success('Dodałeś adnotację do komentarza!');
            return redirect('/profile');   
    }
}



<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\MessageRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\AnswerRequest;
use App\Message;
use App\User;
use App\Answer;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }
    public function index()
    {   
        $sent = Message::where('from_user', \Auth::id())->count();
        $got = Message::where('to_user', \Auth::id())->count();
        $read = Message::where('to_user', \Auth::id())->where('read', 1)->count();
        $notread = Message::where('to_user', \Auth::id())->where('read', 0)->count();
        $sentto = Message::where('from_user', \Auth::id())->latest('created_at')->take(1)->get();
        $gotfrom = Message::where('to_user', \Auth::id())->latest('created_at')->take(1)->get();

        return view('message.index', compact('sent', 'got', 'sentto', 'gotfrom', 'read', 'notread'));
    }

    public function store(MessageRequest $request)
    {
        \Auth::user()->message()->create([
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'message' => $request->input('message'),
            'to_user_id' => $request->input('mess_to_user'),
            'from_user_name' => \Auth::user()->name,
            'to_user_name' => $request->input('from_user_name')
            ]);

        flash()->success('Udało Ci się wysłać prywatną wiadomość!');
        return redirect('/profile/'.$request->input('mess_to_user').'');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $message = Message::findOrFail($id);
        $answers = Answer::paginate(10);

        if($message->to_user == \Auth::id() || $message->from_user == \Auth::id())
        {
            if($message->to_user == \Auth::id())
            {
                Message::where('id', $id)->update(['read' => 1]);
            }

            return view('message.show', compact('message', 'answers', 'check'));
        }
        else
        {
            return back();
        }


    }

    public function got()
    {
        $messages = Message::where('to_user', \Auth::id())->latest('created_at')->paginate(10);
        return view('message.got', compact('messages'));
    }

    public function sent()
    {
        $messages = Message::where('from_user', \Auth::id())->latest('created_at')->paginate(10);
        return view('message.sent', compact('messages'));
    }

    public function storeAnswer(AnswerRequest $request)
    {

        Answer::create([
            'answer' => $request->input('answer'),
            'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
            'user_name' => \Auth::user()->name,
            'to_message' => $request->input('to_message')
            ]);

        flash()->success('Wiadomość prywatna została wysłana!');
        return redirect('/private/'.$request->input('to_message').'');
    }
}
```

Route.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
/*==========This is main controller=============*/
Route::get('/', 'Controller@index');
Route::get('about', 'Controller@about');
Route::get('contact', 'Controller@contact');
Route::get('teammate', 'Controller@teammate');

/*=========Questions Controll===================*/

Route::get('quest', 'QuestController@index');
Route::get('quest/create', 'QuestController@create');
Route::get('quest/{id}', 'QuestController@show');
Route::post('quest', 'QuestController@store');


/*=============Changelog controller==============*/
Route::get('change/create', 'ChangeController@create');
Route::get('change', 'ChangeController@index');
Route::post('change', 'ChangeController@store');

/*=============Admin Controller==================*/
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');

Route::get('admin/group/create', 'AdminController@createGroup');
Route::post('admin/group', 'AdminController@storeGroup');

Route::get('admin/note/create', 'AdminController@createNote');
Route::post('admin/note', 'AdminController@storeNote');

Route::get('admin/section/create', 'AdminController@createSection');
Route::post('admin/section', 'AdminController@storeSection');

Route::get('admin/article/create', 'AdminController@createArticle');
Route::post('admin/article', 'AdminController@storeArticle');
Route::get('admin/article/{id}', 'AdminController@showArticle');
Route::get('admin/article/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@editArticle');
Route::post('admin/article/{id}', 'AdminController@updateArticle');

Route::get('admin/profile', 'AdminController@profile');
Route::get('admin/profile/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@editProfile');
Route::post('admin/profile/{id}', 'AdminController@updateProfile');

/*=============Profile Controller================*/
Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@index');
Route::get('profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@show');
Route::get('profile/{id}/edit', 'ProfileController@edit');
Route::post('profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@update');
Route::post('profile/{id}, 'MessageController@store');
Route::post('profile/{id}, 'CommentController@store');


/*============Character Controller===============*/
Route::get('character/create', 'CharacterController@create');
Route::post('character', 'CharacterController@store');
Route::get('character/online', 'CharacterController@online');


/*============Private Message Controller==========*/
Route::get('private', 'MessageController@index');

Route::get('private/got', 'MessageController@got');
Route::get('private/sent', 'MessageController@sent');
Route::get('private/{id}', 'MessageController@show');
Route::post('private/{id}', 'MessageController@storeAnswer');

Route::controllers(
    [
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same route to access two different functions. That is why when you delete one the code works.

```
//This is wrong.
Route::post('profile/{id}', CommentController@store');
Route::post('profile/{id}', CommentController@storeCommit');
```

You can either mention one as "get" and other as "post" and make the required changes within the respective function to fetch and process data.

```
Route::get('profile/{id}', CommentController@store');
Route::post('profile/{id}', CommentController@storeCommit');
```

Else, give two different routes for the functions

```
Route::post('profile/{id}', CommentController@store');
Route::post('profile/storeCommit/{id}', CommentController@storeCommit');
```

### Updated

Try changing the **third** form like this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method'=>'post', 'route' => array('store.commit', $object->id))) !!}
```

And change your route like this:

```
Route::post('profile/storeCommit/{id}', ['uses' => 'CommentController@storeCommit', 'as' => 'store.commit']);
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I dont understand, how can i do it Route::post('profile/storeCommit/{id}', CommentController@storeCommit'); i need get form from profile/id, not from profile/storeCommit/id

Comment: Can you update your question with the form HTML.? What is the action given to the store commit form ??

Comment: This is answer,which adding to comment, just wait a minute, i add view.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try if that is working for you .

Comment: Not working, i getting error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

Comment: I'm getting error that field title and message of MessageController not be empty , although I try to add reply to comment

Comment: No need to change all the forms.. Only change the third form.. I have updated the answer. please check

Comment: Ok so tell me how i should do routes, look at my routes in the main post.

Comment: And i added your post to view and route and when i adding Comment, is good, adding Commit is good too, but when i want update user profile or send Private Message, i getting error "Comment Field cant be empty"

Comment: Ok, i added your code to every forms and everything working, thanks a lot for your help dude!

Comment: Happy that you found the solution.. Thanks :)

Comment: I have question, I installed BBCodeParser: [https://github.com/golonka/BBCodeParser] for BBCode and i want see components on my page, but i must use {!! BBCode::parse('[b]TEST[/b]')!!}, but this working for too HTML, can i turn off HTML code and just using this components from BBCode?

Comment: Sorry !! i have not used BBCodes yet.. But i will check out and if i get any suggestions i will share with you.